# "RNGoogleMobileAdsBannerView" was not found

Tags: react-native, expo, admob, eas, react-native-google-mobile-ads

I have the next error:

`ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNGoogleMobileAdsBannerView" was not found..`

This error is located at:

```
in RNGoogleMobileAdsBannerView (created by BaseAd)
in BaseAd (created by BannerAd)
in BannerAd (created by BannerAd)
in BannerAd (created by HomeMenu)
```

...

In my package.json I have the necessary modules

```
 "expo": "^48.0.0",
 "expo-build-properties": "~0.5.1",
 "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^10.0.0",
```

And when I want to add banner :

```
 BannerAd(props) {
    
    const adUnitID = Platform.select({
      ios: Environment.ADS[Platform.OS].BANNER || TestIds.BANNER,
      android: Environment.ADS[Platform.OS].BANNER || TestIds.BANNER,
    });

    return (
      <BannerAd
        unitId={adUnitID}
        size={BannerAdSize.BANNER}
        requestOptions={{
          requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
        }}
        onAdFailedToLoad={() => <View></View>}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  }
```

I dont know what is happening.

I have reinstalled the modules I have also change sdk expo but I dont fix it.

Comment: any workaround updates on this? facing the same issue trying to use react-native-google-mobile-ads

Comment: Hi try this  : rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npx pod-install (if you're using iOS)

Comment: What is the version of react-native you are using?

Comment: I would suggest deleting the node_modules installing the modules again. But wait for some time for any other answers.

Comment: Please use the `expo-dev-client` with eas build to fix this. This issue occurs when you try running the using expo go

https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/installation/

Comment: https://medium.com/react-native-expo/migrate-expo-ads-admob-to-react-native-google-mobile-ads-3747b3a3b75e

You have to use the following commands to start the app:
- expo run:android
- expo run:ios

Answer (score 0):

1. first you need to create apk for development

```
eas build -p android --profile development
```

2. install the app on your simulator or device
3. start the app by run the command and open the app directly not **Expo Go App**

```
expo start --dev-client
```

Note:
Adding any library that require **expo-dev-client** need to recreate the apk dev

Reference: https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/